# SOCKS to HTTP proxy chaining using SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, http-proxy, chaining, socks5

I have a server where in order to talk to the outside world it must go through an HTTP proxy.  However, this server is often talking non-HTTP to these external systems.

I'm not able to establish CONNECT tunnels from the server itself, but I am able to use SOCKS.  I am looking to run a SOCKS proxy that will chain incoming requests to the upstream HTTP proxy using the CONNECT command, and then the server will route through the SOCKS proxy.

Can this be done using the `ssh -D` command with proxy jumps/commands?